# Is there a good javascript fallback library for newly supported functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm wondering if there is a good fallback javascript library out there that creates non-supported functions for functions that are defined in newer ECMA specifications. I'm using a library that uses a bunch of functions supported only in newer browsers, and so I'd like to fill those functions in instead of having to rewrite the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) does that to as much of an extent as it can.